# HOG + SVM implementation is not finding the correct number of faces

Tags: python, opencv

Team:

I am trying to find faces using the HOG+SVM implementation provided by OpenCV. No matter how I change my stride and scaling, the numver of faces detected are not accurate. While teh same image when passed to DLIB finds the faces correctly. I am using "Ellen's 2014 selfie @ Oscar" image which has 10 faces (excluding the 2 which are not completely visible).

Please suggest what else I can change to improve the accuracy.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


imageFilename = "123.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(imageFilename)

width = int(image.shape[1] * 30 / 100)
height = int(image.shape[0] * 30 / 100) 


#image = cv2.resize(image, (width,height))
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

print("Input Image Shape",image.shape)


#initialize the HOG descriptor/person detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
# Human detection
(rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(image, winStride=(4, 4),padding=(8, 8), scale=1.02,
                                        #useMeanshiftGrouping=True
                                        )

print("Faces found", len(rects))
# draw bounding boxes
for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Face Recognition", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

```
Input Image Shape (410, 614, 3)
Faces found 8
```

Input Image:
[image]

Output Image:
[image]

Comment: `HOG+SVM ` is a very old method and is more applicable for single face, use mtcnn for good performance. https://github.com/ipazc/mtcnn

Comment: Thanks Zabir. Doesnt `DLIB's detector method` use `HOG+SVM` internally? I remember reading it somewhere. DLIB is perfectly detecting the 10 faces.

Comment: yes, but cnn based detector has more accuracy http://dlib.net/cnn_face_detector.py.html

Comment: As of now i dont want to use Deep Learning techniques. Hence trying to understand how HOG+SVM's accuracy can be increased. What confuses me is, DLIB works fine but the pure implementation isnt Am sure the optimization part plays an important role but as you can see in the output image, it says 8 faces are detected but the bounding boxes are not around faces either.

Answer (score 0):

It has been trained for Pedestrian detection, most likely using the [INRIA Pedestrian dataset](https://dbcollection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datasets/inria_ped.html). There is also a pretrained HOG detector trained on the Daimler Pedestrian detection dataset in OpenCV.

This is not intended for face detection, but rather for Pedestrian detection. Have a look at

It is outperformed by newer techniques nowadays.

Comment: Hi Catree:
Thanks for the input. I was experimenting and wanted to find if HOG+SVM can detect faces. Looks like DLIB uses the concept in a different way. 

One more question:
Is there no way HOG+SVM combo can detect just faces? Do we need to train our own model to achieve this?